# Having bad requests in Paypal express checkput client side rest

Tags: laravel, paypal, client-side, express-checkout

I have laravel project and want to integrate paypal express checkout using client side rest. I have several problems.

1. Clicking on paypal button for making payment I have these errors:

```
POST https://c.paypal.com/v1/r/d/b/p1 400 (Bad Request)
POST https://c.paypal.com/v1/r/d/b/p2 400 (Bad Request)
GET https://c6.paypal.com/v1/r/d/b/p3?f=EC-19893223FU9150749&s=HERMES_SIGNIN 400 (Bad Request)
```

2. Also have this error:

   > Request listener already exists for xcomponent_delegate_ppcheckout on domain * for specified window

but I don't have `listeners.js` in my project

3. And last question. Do I need to have curl request to paypal api, if I am using client side rest.

This is my code.

```
  paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production
        client: {
        sandbox:    'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R',
        production: 'EFPOKHzlSKXUGm9z615EopgdiqkKqVTfMayOzyadr06mWDe3NwaIKwBr7yZTpKZQbLisQ8WT5vIh2gyn'
    },
    commit: true,
    payment: function(actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: '5', currency: 'USD' }
                }
            ]
        });
    },
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            window.alert('Payment Complete!');
            console.log('The payment was authorized!');
            console.log('Payment ID = ',   data.paymentID);
            console.log('PayerID = ', data.payerID);
        });
    },
    onCancel: function(data) {
        console.log('The payment was cancelled!');
    }

}, '#paypal-button-container');
```

I was looking on this tutorial:

> https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/paypal-rest-api.md

There are curl requests, but can anyone explain why do we need those curl request in client side case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Firstly, can you try clearing your cookies? And if you still get the errors can you link to your site so I can try to reproduce the problem

Comment: I cant give you link,cause I am trying on my local. Maybe it's working not 100% because I am on local, on live maybe it will work perfect? Now titme to time the post request has error Error: Request to post https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment failed with 401 error and payment pop up does not appear, clicking once again on paypal button, the it works. I dont get why it works time to time.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing 400's and 401's too - not only in my own code, but in the live demo's on PayPal's site.

I contacted my account manager and sent some logs etc, and was told this is a sandbox issue and it should be fine on the production system. Indeed, switching to production the pop up opens successfully every time.

So it seems the advice for now is ignore the occasional failures on the sandbox, production works fine! I plan to do some final testing on the live system before rolling out the change.

You don't need any of the curl logic from that link for client side, the Javascript you've posted should be all you need. I'd recommend building off PayPal's samples here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client, and the REST API docs here in case any of the other JSON fields are useful: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that sandbox does not work for 100%. I have one more question. If I am using client side rest, does  onAuthorize function enough to be sure that the payment was succesful. Or I need to make curl post approval request to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/". $PaymentID . "/execute" link to approve the payment?

Comment: There sample code says calling `actions.payment.execute()` from onAuthorize should be all that's needed, although I would test and make sure the funds are transferred at that point as "execute" has a different meaning in their normal REST API and still requires authorization and capture afterwards. We had an existing REST API implementation so I'm not doing anything to the payment in onAuthorize, just redirecting to our old code which executes, authorizes and captures.